# Can we upgrade spring version in dxa from current 3.2.8 version

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

We currently have a deployed and working dxa-web-application-java in production. This is currently using Spring version 3.2.8. Due to some features that we want to implement that is only available in latest versions of Spring, we want to upgrade the version. Is it possible to do so and if so can anyone please share the steps.

Also all the configuration and initialization is done in the Core module. How can we configure some of our own classes in the example webapp module?

> Update 20/02/2017

I am using DXA 1.1 and Tridion 7.1.0

Comment: Which versions of Tridion and DXA are you using?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Tridion 2013 SP1, that implies that the CD libraries are used in-process and hence the version of Spring is dictated by CD (or at least: the version of Spring you use should be 100% compatible with the version used by CD) and CD 2013 SP1 uses Spring 3.1.

Indeed, early DXA Java releases used Spring 3.2.8, but that has been found problematic and hence DXA Java 1.3 was downgraded to Spring 3.1.4.

So: the official answer is "no, because you will get compatibility issues with CD libraries".

If you upgrade to SDL Web 8 (CIS/CIL) this CD compatibility problem disappears (CIL doesn't use Spring), but the DXA Framework still uses Spring 3.1.4 (mainly because we also still support 2013 SP1).

In DXA 2.0 (in development) we have finally upgraded to Spring 4.3. This did require some changes in DXA because of incompatibilities in Spring.

Regarding configuration: note that "DXA Java 1.1" release does not exist; the first official DXA Java release was 1.2.  Earlier versions were not official releases.  Regardless, the way how DXA Java is configured has changed significant in early releases. I would strongly recommend to upgrade to a recent, official version.  Since you're on 2013 SP1, DXA 1.6 is the most current release you can use.

Comment: Thank you for the update.So which latest official version uses Spring 4.x?

Comment: There is no official released version of DXA which uses Spring 4.x yet. As mentioned, DXA 1.x releases still use Spring 3.1 and DXA 2.0 is not released yet.

Comment: Is there an expected release date for Java DXA 2.0?

Comment: Projected release of DXA 2.0 is end of Q3 2017. There will be CTP releases end of Q1 and Q2.

Comment: Note that DXA 2.0 does not support SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, BTW.